# Run Jupyter Notebook on google cloud compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I used to run Jupyter Notebooks from google compute engine instances perfectly few weeks back using external ip and setting up the firewall rules.

I basically used [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) procedure to set it up some time back.

But when I tried today, jupyter notebook wont open. It's just tries loading but doesnt open up. I recreated my instance, rebuilt the firewall rules but it doesnt work.

Is there any more procedure I need to follow to start jupyter notebook from compute engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I turned out it didnt work because of my institute wifi (for some reason I don't know it doesnt allow). It works on using proxy/VPN or other wifi.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

I found a similar issue which you will find on [github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3209). If it does not resolve your issue, then check your logs in [stackdriver](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and open a new issue at [github jupyter forum](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=) with detailed logs.